# ¿Como puedo eliminar el texto de la caja de texto en Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

he intentado eliminar el texto introducido en la caja de texto del TextField, pero no lo he logrado ya que este texto de ingresa a una lista creada. Intenté con un GestureDetector y que al darle en agregar le de un valor en la lista de un texto vacío pero solo lo agrega.

````
  Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final List<String> tasks = <String>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('App ToDo'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            onSubmitted: _addItem,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: tasks.length, itemBuilder: _addWidget),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _addItem(value) {
    setState(() {
      tasks.add(value);
    });
  }
}```
Es así de simple el código pero no puedo lograr que elimine el texto, he visto opciones pero solo hace más que complicar el código, incluso ya leí sobre el TextField pero no logro encontrar algo que me ayude.
Ni videos en inglés o español, ya que en esos solo crean una variable que guarde solo un elemento y no aplica demasiado a lo que yo tengo aquí, algo como este *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MaPLaU8-IS4&t=73s* >cita
````

Comment: cada vez que agregues un elemento quieres limpiar la caja de texto, cierto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso del `TextEditingController` y asignarlo al `TextField`.

```dart
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
 final List<String> tasks = <String>[];
 final textController = TextEditingController();

// lo asignas

       TextField(
           controller: textController,
           onSubmitted: _addItem,
         ),

// Y luego cada vez que quieras limpiarlo solo llamas a `clear()`

 _addItem(value) {
   textController.clear();
   setState(() {
     tasks.add(value);
   });
```

Te dejo este link como referencia: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes

Comment: Me sirvió, muchas gracias y gracias por la referencia, la estaré checando por si necesito otra cosa.

Comment: dale, no te olvides de marcar la pregunta como resuelta :) , te dejo mi canal para cuando llegues a ver cosas más avanzadas www.youtube.com/diegoveloper